# which path has to be specified in httpGet handler in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I just started learning Kubernetes and I am confused about the 'path' parameter in httpGet handler in kubernetes probes. can anyone explain about that please?

Answer (score 0):

`path` is used to declare the service's `routing address` / `interface address` / `API`

When using `livenessProbe.httpGet` as a health checker, a health query is required, i.e. it calls a uri to confirm the service health based on the returned status code

The composition of this uri: `scheme://podIp:port/path` == `http://10.244.171.183:8080/index.html`

Comment: That's great, thank you